# DataGridView event to catch a constraint exception?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a list of employees, some of them are attached to groups. The model is:

Mitarbeiter 1 --> n MitarbeiterGruppen
Mitarbeiternr --> Mitarbeiternr

I also have a datagridview which shows the employees (Mitarbeiter). Which would be the best event to catch the exception? Which exception should it be? And if the exception is thrown how can I do something like undo recordset?

This is the event I picked, before I tested a bit with different exceptions, but I never got the right one. And very ugly, if the error (of course) is thrown, I can't end it.

```
    Private Sub DataGridMA_UserDeletingRow(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCancelEventArgs) Handles DataGridMA.UserDeletingRow
    e.Cancel = True 'Danke. Löschen übernehmen ab jetzt wir

    Dim response As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show( _
    "Eintrag löschen? Bitte beachten Sie, dass zuerst die Gruppenzugehörigkeiten gelöscht werden müssen!", "Datensatz löschen", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2)

    If response = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then 'Eintrag löschen
        e.Row.DataGridView.Rows.Remove(e.Row)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please  stop adding tags to titles.  It is just noise and most cool kids use filters to view tag topics they are interested in.

Comment: ok, I didn't know I thought it would be a benefit in finding posts. Thanks for the remark

Comment: ah you edited it by yourself, thanks

Comment: [Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)

Comment: why not, but now you told me, and I won't do it again

Comment: but perhaps you have also some tipps to answer my question

Comment: Use a Try Catch to get the exception if one is thrown? Not sure if that is what you are asking

Comment: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/NET/nets5p4.html

Comment: thx I know how to use try...catch...finally I'm just not sure what type of exception will be thrown an in which event